# What is the fastest way to remove specifc elements from all sub arrays or an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
"output" : [
  {
    "zip":35004,
    "state":"AL",
    "City":"Acmar",
    "lat":33.584132,
    "lng":-86.51557
  },
  {
    "zip":35005,
    "state":"AL",
    "City":"Adamsville",
    "lat":33.588437,
    "lng":-86.959727
  }
]
```

Now how do I remove 'lat' and 'long' from all the sub-arrays. I want an output like this:

```
"output" : [
  {
    "zip":35004,
    "state":"AL",
    "City":"Acmar"            
  },
  {
    "zip":35005,
    "state":"AL",
    "City":"Adamsville"           
  }
]
```

What is the fastest possible way to do this?

Comment: The fastest way is to start with :)

Comment: and if you get stuck or error then post here :)

Comment: I assume you mean "sub-objects" and not "sub-arrays". There are a bunch of ways to do it, including looping through the array, using ES5 methods, and easiest lodash/underscore. But fastest? Does it matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess

```
for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
     delete row[i].lat;
     delete row[i].long;
}
```

For is faster than forEach and using delete is obviously

Comment: That works, I cannot see why anything would be faster. Since you need to modify every single element, no search algorithm will improve upon it, it still needs to be O(n). I will upvote this.

Comment: Would be funnier if instead of "lat" and "long" it were "short" and "long". Uh, I think I need more sleep...

Comment: Hey @RaxWunter is `for` materially faster than `forEach`? Why?

Comment: You can run code http://jsfiddle.net/k37xn0pg/ 
forEach involves function calling and additional scopes, it needs time for that

Comment: Forget that, someone already put it up in jsperf. http://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach Holy cow, simple for loop is 4.5x faster than forEach! And I did it in latest Safari which natively supports ES5 forEach. Thanks, I learned something new. I would upvote your answer again (but SO only allows it once).